# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos^a (x)\sin(bx) dx$ using Mathematica

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

Consider the integral $$I(a,b)=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos^a (x)\sin(bx) dx$$
where $a\geq 0$ and $b\geq 0$

> I am requesting a code in Wolfram Mathematica so as to write the non negativity restrictions of $a$ and $b$ and to find an answer for the above integral in terms of Hypergeometric functions or other functions.

Sorry, I am new to Wolfram Mathematica.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try the Integrate command? V 13.2 can do it. Here is the command `ClearAll[a, b, x]; Integrate[Cos[x]^a*Sin[b*x], {x, 0, Pi/2},  Assumptions -> {a >= 0, b >= 0}]` It gives ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZfh6.png)

Comment: FullSimplify gives same thing. `Hypergeometric2F1[1, (1/2)*(2 + a - b), (1/2)*(2 - a - b), -1]/(a + b) + Hypergeometric2F1[1, (1/2)*(2 + a + b), (1/2)*(2 - a + b), -1]/(-a + b) + 
  (2^(-1 - a)*Pi*Gamma[1 + a]*Sin[b*Pi])/((-Cos[a*Pi] + Cos[b*Pi])*Gamma[(1/2)*(2 + a - b)]*Gamma[(1/2)*(2 + a + b)])`  screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrmuS.png)

Comment: @Nasser Thank you so much. But then when $a=0$ and $b=0$, we have by direct computation by hand, $I(a,b)=\pi/2$ but in the answer given by mathematica it has $(a+b)$ and $(a-b)$ in the denominator, which makes $I(a,b)$ not defined for $a=0,b=0$. Please see if I am missing something trivial.

Comment: Re ÷ 0: Have you heard of `Limit`? -- "Please do 'full simplify'": Sheesh! Look it up.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Sorry, but what do you mean by "Re" in Re÷0?

Comment: Isn't division by zero the problem you're referring to, when you say $I(a,b)$ is not defined for $a=0,b=0$? Or did I misunderstand? Or overlooked some other problem, because I didn't investigate very far?

Comment: `Pi/2`??!! If `b` is 0 then the integrand is 0 so the definite integral is 0.

Answer (score 4):

For $0\le x \le {\pi\over2}$, $a\ge0$, $b\ge0$,
we have $0 \le \cos x \le 1$ and $0 \le \sin bx \le bx$,
and therefore the integrand is bounded by
$0 \le \cos^a x \sin bx \le bx$ and the integral by $0 \le I(a,b) \le {\pi ^2 \over 8}\,b$, which is also the asymptotic value as $a\rightarrow0, b\rightarrow0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable inputs.

Answer (score 3):

This is getting too long to keep using comments. You need to use Limits for the special cases, then it works

```
ClearAll[a, b, x]
sol = Integrate[Cos[x]^a*Sin[b*x], {x, 0, Pi/2}, Assumptions -> {a >= 0, b >= 0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Limit[sol, {a -> 0, b -> 0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

i.e. do not do

```
 sol /. {a -> 0, b -> 0}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Tried Maple 2023 and it can't solve it. Maxima 5.46 can't do it, giac can't do it. Sympy can't do it. Tried Fricas 1.3.8 and it also can't solve it, it says:

```
(1) -> integrate(cos(x)^a*sin(b*x),x=0..%pi/2)    
   (1)  "potentialPole"
```

So far only Mathematica can integrate it and says the answer is zero when `a->0,b->0`. Rubi is not meant to be used on definite integration.

> see if we can get the answer of that limit as π/2

I do not know why you think the limit should be `Pi/2` as `a->0,b->0`

Just plotting the integrand as `a->0,b->0` shows clearly that area under the curve is shrinking more and more to zero. Since integration is the area under the curve, then zero seems like the correct result.

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Cos[x]^a*Sin[b*x], {x, 0, Pi/2}, 
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 1}}],
 {{a, 2, "a"}, 2, 0.01, -0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled", 
  ContinuousAction -> False},
 {{b, 2, "b"}, 2, 0.01, -0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled", 
  ContinuousAction -> False},
 TrackedSymbols :> {a, b}
 
 ]
```

Comment: See(https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=limit+Hypergeometric2F1%281%2C%282%2Ba-b%29%2F2%2C%282-a-b%29%2F2%2C-1%29%2F%28a%2Bb%29+as+a-%3E0%2C+b-%3E0) I am getting limit does not exists

Comment: @Max I can't answer why Mathematica does not give $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and if its answer is correct or not. I assume that zero is correct answer since that is what it gives. If you think this is the wrong answer, it could be a bug. I do not know myself now. I tried Maple to compare, but Maple can not solve it.

Comment: **So the limit of I(a,b)  as a→0,b→0  is indeterminate?**  No. The limit is zero. It is when you plugin in $a=0,b=0$ that you get indeterminate. You need to use the Limit command instead.

Comment: Ok then please see if we can get the answer of that limit as $\pi/2$.

Comment: Ok. My bad. I got it now. Thanks a lot.:)

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

When `b == a` the integral simplifies to

```
int[a_] = Assuming[a >= 0,
  Integrate[Cos[x]^a*Sin[a*x], {x, 0, Pi/2}] // FullSimplify]

(* -2^(-1 - a) (E^(I a π) Beta[-1, -a, 1 + a] + π Cot[a π]) *)

Plot[int[a], {a, 0, 20}]
```

[image]

Near `a == 0`

```
Plot[int[a], {a, 0, 1/100}, WorkingPrecision -> 25]
```

[image]

This is consistent with the other answers that show the limit is zero.

**EDIT:** To find the maximum

```
argMax = FindRoot[int'[a] == 0, {a, 3/2}, WorkingPrecision -> 20] // N

(* {a -> 1.4304} *)

max = int[a] /. argMax // Chop

(* 0.522152 *)
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is awesome. I have a question. In the answer we have complex numbers involved, but the integral was real. How to get a real answer? Do we have to take the real part of the answer?

Comment: The presence of the complex constant `I` does not mean that the expression is complex. If it were complex, the plot would not show. However, when evaluating--for the cancellation of the imaginary parts to occur precisely enough--precision control is generally required. In the second plot, a `WorkingPrecision` was specified to switch from machine precision to arbitrary-precision. If instead you use `Plot[int[a], {a, 0, 1/100}]` there are gaps in the plot were the lack of precision results in complex artifacts. In that case, `Re` could be used to remove the artifacts.

Comment: Thanks. Then how do we get a real answer from the result? Do we have to take real parts?

Comment: `int[a]` is real for `a >= 0`; it merely appears complex. You can, for example, use `int[0.1] // Real` or `int[0.1] // Chop` to remove the negligible artifacts.

Comment: Please help me to get a real answer. I will with utmost respect accept your answer.

Comment: Again, `int[a]` is real. What is the actual problem? What are you trying to do that you cannot do?

Comment: How is int[a] real? It contains $e^(i \pi a)$ which I think makes it imaginary.

Comment: Real numbers and real functions can contain complex elements. When evaluated, the imaginary components all cancel out to produce real values. For example, see [`casus irreducibilis`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link. It was useful

Comment: @Max This link is even more useful: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/282220/82985 please note my comments in the answer. In fact it may still be almost Real, but in some cases you can get antiderivative that is just -I Pi/2 difference as part of the whole +C business. That is not going to plot.