# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos^a (x)\sin(ax) dx$ using Mathematica

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

Consider the integral $$I(a)=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos^a (x)\sin(ax) dx$$
where $a\geq 0$

I am trying to evaluate the above integral using Mathematica using the following code :

```
int[a_] = Assuming[a >= 0,
  Integrate[Cos[x]^a*Sin[a*x], {x, 0, Pi/2}] // FullSimplify]
```

The answer we get is `-2^(-1 - a) (E^(I a π) Beta[-1, -a, 1 + a] + π Cot[a π])`

Problem is that the definite integral was real for $a\geq 0$ but the answer contains imaginary number $i=\sqrt{-1}$. How do we get a real answer?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Related (and more general): https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/282193/evaluate-int-0-pi-2-cosa-x-sinbx-dx-using-mathematica

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> answer contains imaginary number i . How do we get a real answer?

Just because the answer contains $i$ does not necessarily mean the overall value is also complex. it depends on what is inside the expression (what type of special functions are involved, some cancelations that can occur and so on).

You can see that by plotting the antiderivative for some range of $a$, that it does plot OK. It will not have plotted if the result was complex (you would get blank plot if there were complex values anywhere in the result).

```
 sol = Integrate[Cos[x]^a*Sin[a*x], {x, 0, Pi/2}, Assumptions -> a >= 0]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 Plot[sol, {a, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In addition, you can evaluate numerically the antiderivative for some $a$ values. They are all real

```
 Table[Limit[sol, a -> a0], {a0, 0.1, 3, .1}] // Chop
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can see that also from evaluating Beta

```
  Limit[E^(I a Pi) Beta[-1, -a, 1 + a] , a -> 1.2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It is real value even though there is `E^(I a Pi)` in there. This happens in this case because the incomplete beta function can generate complex value and this cancels the complex values coming from `E^(I a Pi)`

```
 p1= Limit[Beta[-1, -a, 1 + a], a -> 1.2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
  p2 = Limit[E^(I a Pi), a -> 1.2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
  p1*p2
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So the rule of the thumb is: Just because an expression has $i$ this does not always implies the overall expression value will also be complex. It depends.

Comment: +1 for your answer

Comment: What is the limit of the answer as $a\to 0$?

Comment: @Max Mathematica can not evaluate the limit as `a->0`. But it can for any value greater than zero. `Limit[Beta[-1, -a, 1 + a], a -> 0]` returns unevaluated. It could be due to branch cut at this value.

Comment: Thanks you a lot.

Comment: I suspect the Limit limitation arises from Series balking at having the variable of interest appear in more than one argument of Beta.

Comment: Also one might show the integrand allows for swapping limit and integral. Which gives the expected result of zero.

Comment: "Just because the answer contains i does not necessarily mean the overall value is also complex" Even worse, in some cases you can get antiderivative that is just  -I Pi/2 difference as part of the whole +C business. That is not going to plot. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16885/how-to-evaluate-this-indefinite-integral-csc4x-sinx/16896#comment671095_16896

Comment: So why is E^(-((4 I \[Pi])/5)) Beta[-1, -(6/5), 11/5] // N is different from -(-1)^(1/5) Beta[-1, -(6/5), 11/5] // N even though we can get second from first (even with FullSimplify)? Also why Wolfram Cloud has bigger error in   Limit[E^(I a Pi) Beta[-1, -a, 1 + a] , a -> 1.2]?

Comment: Posted on the previous comment topic: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/282358/82985

Answer (score 1):

Workaround: using formula:

$$\sum _{j=1}^a \frac{\binom{a}{j} \sin (2 j x)}{2^a}=\cos ^a(x) \sin (a x)$$
We have:

$\int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} \cos ^a(x) \sin (a x) \, dx=2^{-1-a} \gamma +2^{-1-a} a \, _3F_2(1,1,1-a;2,2;-1)+2^{-1-a} \psi (1+a)$

The answer **not** contains imaginary number.

```
S = Sum[Integrate[Binomial[a, j]*Sin[2 j x ]/2^a, {x, 0, Pi/2}], {j, 1, a}] // Expand

(*2^(-1 - a) EulerGamma + 2^(-1 - a) a HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 1, 1 - a}, {2, 2}, -1] + 
2^(-1 - a) PolyGamma[0, 1 + a]*)

Limit[S, a -> 0]
(* 0 *)
S /. a -> 0
(* 0*)
```

**EDITED: 15.03.2023**

My formula works for $a\in \mathbb{R}$ ,see below:

```
int[a_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[Cos[x]^a*Sin[a*x], {x, 0, Pi/2}, 
Method -> "LocalAdaptive"] // Quiet;
Plot[{int[a], S}, {a, -1, 3}, PlotLegends -> {"Numeric", "Symbolic"}, PlotStyle -> {Red, {Dashed, Black}}]
Plot[{int[a] - S}, {a, -1, 3}, PlotLegends -> {"Residuals"}]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. +1. But $a$ is a non negative real number, so the sum cannot run from $j=1$ to $a$. Please help me with this. Most humbly I will accept your answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Please show using mathematica or otherwise that for $a\geq 0$, $$\int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} \cos ^a(x) \sin (a x) \, dx=2^{-1-a} \gamma +2^{-1-a} a \, _3F_2(1,1,1-a;2,2;-1)+2^{-1-a} \psi (1+a)$$ I will with utmost respect accept your answer

Comment: @Max .This is not the right forum for math and proofs. Maybe you’ll have better luck at the math StackExchange.