# Trace shows Linux has worse error than Windows in 1/(-1.)^1.2

Tags: numerics, number-representation

So I questioned why there are differences between Wolfram Cloud and Windows 11 [Evaluate $\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos^a (x)\sin(ax) dx$ using Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/282217/evaluate-int-0-pi-2-cosa-x-sinax-dx-using-mathematica/282220#comment703365_282220)

```
E^(-((4 I \[Pi])/5)) Beta[-1, -(6/5), 11/5] // N
```

I FullSimplified as that gets better results (even though it should not, this is school math, there difference just happens somehow when -0.8090169943749475/0.587785252292473 changes to -0.8090169943749473/0.5877852522924732 with no reason whatsoever, but **that is not what this question is about**):

```
E^(-((4 I \[Pi])/5)) Beta[-1, -(6/5), 11/5] //FullSimplify//N
```

So, the result on windows is `-6.6974 - 8.88178*10^-16 I` (actually true value is `-6.697403197294095 - 8.881784197001252-16 I`) vs result on linux cloud that is `-6.6974 - 1.33227*10^-15 I`.

**Why do you think that happens?**

Well, I did trace as here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/271955/82985

and got the following result after 20 minutes of debug. Apparently it gets to

1/(-1.)^1.2 and not only lowers accuracy (why?) and thus loses one 1 in the complex part (on windows and linux), but it also makes a mistake in the real part (only on Linux).

That, that is why. You are aware this exists, right? https://core-math.gitlabpages.inria.fr/

Libm comparisions also exist: https://members.loria.fr/PZimmermann/papers/accuracy.pdf

```
Trace[-(-1)^(1/5) Beta[-1, -(6/5), 11/5] // N, TraceInternal -> True, 
 TraceDepth -> 10]
```

will give this on my Windows 11: https://pastebin.com/h9espi8G (wolfram cloud: https://pastebin.com/DGHQzaQX).

P.S. So there are 3 bugs here: on Linux rounding for floating precision (that cannot be controlled by N as in for 1/(-1.)^1.2) is horrible, even on Windows the error is just off-by-one in last digit, maybe because of AMD/Microsoft libm. Still an error. 2nd bug is that the general solver has somehow variable precision, not equal to this floating default and yet the precision in complex part is lower on one digit (or it just gets an error and sees 0 not 1). 3rd bug is that on windows it can sometimes just copy values through trace wrong with no reason (maybe it is some precision autotracking, dunno).

P.S.2 Opened a thread in community: https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2851685

Comment: You can specify the numerical accuracy when using N. For instance, N[E^(-((4 I \[Pi])/5)) Beta[-1, -(6/5), 11/5], 100] gives it to 100 decimal places.

Comment: And btw, it is not going to work with 1/(-1.)^1.2, only with N[1/(-1)^(12/10), 50], yet there is an error on linux inside the trace of the calculation.

Comment: (1) On `"13.2.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (November 18, 2022)"` versus
`"13.2.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (December 12, 2022)"` I get a 1 ulp difference in numericizing one factor `N[ Beta[-1, -(6/5), 11/5]]` and no difference in numericizing the `-(-1)^(1/5)` factor from the full-simplified expression. This accounts for the results on Macos and Linux. (2) Different rounding errors from different expressions should be expected (it's a chapter in most num. anal. books), so if there is a point to comparing simplified and unsimplified expressions, it needs to be made clearer.

Comment: (2) We are not comparing FullSimplified and not FullSimplified expressions. At least I do not. We compare only FullSimplified expressions, but on Linux (Cloud) and Windows.

Comment: BTW, you can get to perfect result by doing  -1. (0.8090169943749475 + 
   0.587785252292473 I) (5.418313004792032 - 3.936634828025925 I).

Comment: My (2) was a reaction to your claim "with no reason whatsover," which is not true. Of course,  you go on to say, "**that is not what this question is about.**" So I understand it is not related to the main question. (I don't know why you want to obfuscate the issue with `FullSimplify`, if the question is really about numericizing `-(-1)^(1/5) Beta[-1, -(6/5), 11/5]`. The result of `FullSimplify` is the same on all systems, isn't it?)

Comment: This seems a better beta, at least on the above example: `myBeta[x_, a_, b_] = MeijerGReduce[Beta[x, a, b], x] // Activate;`

Comment: After FullSimplify there is less of an error in both windows and linux.

Comment: "less of an error": so you are comparing simplified and non-simplified expressions. -- That aside (it seems irrelevant to the other part of the question), it's still unclear to me whether are you interested in evaluating the original FullSimplified expression with `Beta[]` in the body of the question or just the expression `1/(-1.)^1.2` in the title?

Comment: From Trace you can see the biggest error in original FullSimplified expression happens in 1/(-1.)^1.2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the problem, despite attempts get clarification.

So far I'm not sure there is much more to this than to the following, this-is-school-math, behavior:

```
Sqrt[3. (4./3. - 1.) - 1.]
(*  0. + 1.49012*10^-8 I  *)
```

But in this instance, this behavior is predicted.  In the OP's case, there is the added variability of different systems using different libraries on different CPUs.

About the variability,
my Mac M1 Pro and the online Linux
compute different values for $1/z$ for some complex values of $z$,
and neither produces a correctly rounded result all the time.
So far, all I've witnessed is incorrect rounding (<1ulp error).

If we consider complicated expressions (that is, involving more than one arithmetic operation), such as the OP's `1/(-1.)^1.2` that arises in `Trace[N@Beta[-1, -(6/5), 11/5], TraceInternal -> True]`, we have to consider error propagation and additional rounding errors at each step.  Even if operations are correctly rounded, the errors get propagated, and subtractive cancellation may lead to large relative error.  One may also have correlated errors that cancel each other out. Different formulas have different numerical properties, even if they are school-math equivalent.  For instance `(-1.)^(-1.2)` is a better way to compute `1/(-1.)^1.2`, if you have a good `Power` function. (Possibly the `Beta[]` algorithm should be criticized for this.)

Now, interesting things happen in evaluating `1/(-1.)^1.2` on the Mac M1 and on Linux.  The Mac computes `z1 = (-1.)^1.2` correctly rounded and Linux does not; and neither the Mac nor Linux compute `1/z1` correctly rounded; however, on Linux, the two rounding errors cancel each other out, so that the result of `1/(-1.)^1.2` ends up correctly rounded. One might criticize the complex arithmetic of both systems for division not being correctly rounded; however, if complex division is done in real double-precision, then it is a complicated operation (in the above sense) and entails multiple roundings and error propagation.

That said, neither system computes `1/(-1)^(6/5)` correctly rounded. That should be no surprise, since `6/5` is not the same as `1.2`, since `1.2` equals `5404319552844595/4503599627370496` exactly, in binary double precision. (This applies to `11/5` and `2.2` in the `Beta[]` calculation; indeed, the error is 4 times as great, due to the way the bits line up in the binary expansion of the fractions. This rounding error is then propagated through the computation of `Beta[]`.)

It is not made clear in the OP what is so horrible, but I infer it is that the imaginary part of a real result is nonzero in the first expression in the OP, whether simplified or not. I have not looked into how expensive it is to make complex arithmetic be correctly rounded, and that seems to be a significant source of error. (The error in the `Beta[]` cannot be completely traced.)  The sources cited seem to consider real arithmetic and functions only.  IEEE 754 does not treat complex functions (e.g. "$pow (x, y)$ signals the invalid operation exception for finite $x < 0$ and finite non-integer $y$").  I think most applications can tolerate errors of a couple ulp.  This seems inevitable to me in computations that involve several operations such `1/(-1.)^1.2` or the `Beta[]` one (unless it is possible to write a special routine for your problem). *Mathematica* provides arbitrary precision for applications in which such small errors are too large.

Finally, I will point out that it is easy to write a numerically better routine in *Mathematica* for the OP's initial problem:

```
myBeta[x_, a_, b_] = 
  MeijerGReduce[Beta[x, a, b], x] // Activate // FunctionExpand;

Block[{Beta = myBeta},
 E^(-((4 I π)/5)) Beta[-1, -(6/5), 11/5] // FullSimplify // N
 ]

(*  -6.6974  *)
```

**Appendix**

*What $1.2$ and $2.2$ equal in binary floating-point*

> [image: Table of bit expansions of 1.2, 2.2]
>
> Binary expansions of 1.2, 2.2. The color squares indicate a 1, the white squares indicate a 0, and the gray squares indicate a nonexistant or insignificant bit.

Comment: "such as the OP's 1/(-1.)^1.2, which arises in Trace[N@Beta[-1, -(6/5), 11/5], TraceInternal -> True]" Nice! Yes, apparently the issue is that it cannot see that this is just 1: N[1/(-1.)^1.2*E^(-((4 I \[Pi])/5))], even if you increase second parameter of N. Yet if you do FullSimplify of the second part it sees it is 1. + 0. I.

Comment: "It is not made clear in the OP what is so horrible, but I infer it is that the imaginary part of a real result is nonzero in the first expression in the OP, whether simplified or not." That too, but I mostly do not like different behaviour on different OS. Is MeijerGReduce faster than out of the box or slower?

Comment: (Note to poster, not Michael E2): Different behaviors on different operating systems is generally due to (1) different libraries, (2) different arithmetic processors and (3) different compilers. But you knew this. As indicated in responses, one can use software arithmetic instead. It's slower by far, but will generally not show such system dependencies. As for those dependencies, I really do not see a way to avoid them.

Comment: So you use Intel libm from OneAPI on windows? Cause it has complex.h. Ideally you would use that on linux too. https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/dpcpp-cpp-compiler/developer-guide-reference/2023-0/use-the-intel-oneapi-dpc-c-compiler-math-library.html

Comment: I have only one computer to use, plus whatever is on WolframCloud. I don't have access to Windows (on either Intel or AMD). (Or maybe you're asking Daniel?) `MeijerGReduce` converts `Beta` to ${}_2F_1$, so it probably is of similar speed since the trace shows `Beta` calls  ${}_2F_1$.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yep, I asked Daniel. I also noticed it uses Hypergeometric2F1. Can the same be done to remove the complex part in cases like 1/4 (-PolyGamma[0, 1/2 - I Sqrt[2]] + PolyGamma[0, 1 - I Sqrt[2]] - 
   PolyGamma[0, 1/2 + I Sqrt[2]] + PolyGamma[0, 1 + I Sqrt[2]]) // N

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников Re different behavior: That was the initial impetus for IEEE 754 on real floating-point math. The variability was both expensive and life-threatening, so the cost of not standardizing real FP was significant. I suppose the IEEE and industry don't feel a complex FP standard is needed (at this time). Re PolyGamma: I don't know how to prevent the imaginary part, or convert it to an expression that yields a real number. The input is complex, and I think that leads to a complex output. I use something like `result /. z_Complex /; Im[z] == 0 :> Re[z]` to convert.

Comment: Only sqrt() is mandated to be 0.500 ulp by IEEE 754 (and is as such in practice, see accuracy.pdf, and sqrts are also correctly rounded, not just 0.5 ulp), back then perfect algorithms did not exist for other functions. Nowadays they do, and you can bruteforce all values in single precision to be sure.

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников As far as different behavior goes, MKL on Intel Core hardware can produce different results when using the vectorized and non-vectorized version of the same function on the same computer: see [this chat message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39169909#39169909).

Comment: Intel libm is not part of MKL, it is part of Intel compiler, legacy one. New one is based on llvm and llvm has all functions correctly rounded.

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников Are you saying Mathematica no longer uses MKL on Intel processors? My point was simply that the same software (Mathematica) on the same hardware (Mac/Intel) produces different results for seemingly equivalent calculations. It had nothing to do with libm, as far as I can see. You were concerned about different results on different systems. This is different results on the same system.

Comment: OneMKL is not used in M1/M2 macs, that is for sure. Feast, Pardiso, FGMRES, etc. Libm is not part of OneMKL. Libm is C standard library, implementation of math.h and complex.h prototypes. It is part of OneAPI as a whole. Mac should be using https://github.com/libxsmm/libxsmm Intel is dumping some of the worse algorithms of OneMKL there.

Comment: "OneMKL is not used in M1/M2 macs" -- the chat date was in 2017, which was well before M1.

Comment: @MichaelE2 BTW, using actual float representation can you calculate where it is more correct, Linux or Windows for  1/(-1.)^1.2 (where two float numbers are not perfectly equal to -1 and 6/5). I said in the header it is Linux that is less correct, but now I have doubts.

Answer (score 10):

This made me curious.

I work under macos on Apple Silicon. I get these results:

```
a = E^(-((4 I \[Pi])/5)) Beta[-1, -(6/5), 11/5] // N
b = E^(-((4 I \[Pi])/5)) Beta[-1, -(6/5), 11/5] // FullSimplify // N
Abs[Re[a] - Re[b]]/Abs[Re[b]]
Abs[Im[a] - Im[b]]/Abs[Im[b]]
Abs[a - b]/Abs[b]
```

> -6.697403197294095 - 1.7763568394002505*^-15 I
>
> -6.697403197294095 - 8.881784197001252*^-16 I
>
> 0.
>
> 1.
>
> 1.3261534262398443*^-16

So it looks as if we had 100% relative error in the imaginary part. But as a complex number, the relative error is almost as low as it can be. I agree, in a perfect world this should not happen, as double complex numbers have separate matissas and exponents for real and imaginary part.

Let's see where this error might come from; let's check the "complicated" functions first:

```
a1 = E^(-((4 I \[Pi])/5)) // N
b1 = E^(-((4 I \[Pi])/5)) // FullSimplify // N
Abs[Re[a1] - Re[b1]]/Abs[Re[b1]]
Abs[Im[a1] - Im[b1]]/Abs[Im[b1]]
Abs[a1 - b1]/Abs[b1]
```

> -0.8090169943749473 - 0.5877852522924732 I
>
> -0.8090169943749475 - 0.5877852522924731 I
>
> 1.3723111286221163*^-16
>
> 1.8888242266968722*^-16
>
> 1.5700924586837752*^-16

So both results are basically as good as it can get with double precision.

```
a2 = Beta[-1, -(6/5), 11/5] // N
b2 = Beta[-1, -(6/5), 11/5] // FullSimplify // N
Abs[Re[a2] - Re[b2]]/Abs[Re[b2]]
Abs[Im[a2] - Im[b2]]/Abs[Im[b2]]
Abs[a2 - b2]/Abs[b2]
```

> 5.418313004792032 - 3.936634828025925 I

> 5.418313004792032 - 3.936634828025925 I

> 0. 

> 0. 

> 0. 

Of course, the `FullSimplify` cannot do anything here.

Okay, but we have

```
a - a1 a2
b - b1 b2
```

> 0.+0.I

> 0.+0.I

So where the heck does the error in `a - b` come from? Just from the multiplication? Indeed! The simple "naive" way to compute the products would be

```
Re[a] == Re[a1] Re[a2] - Im[a1] Im[a2]
Im[a] == Re[a1] Im[a2] + Im[a1] Re[a2]
```

And apprently, that's what *Mathematica* does:

```
Re[a1] Re[a2] - Im[a1] Im[a2] - Re[a]
Re[a1] Im[a2] + Im[a1] Re[a2] - Im[a]
Re[b1] Re[b2] - Im[b1] Im[b2] - Re[b]
Re[b1] Im[b2] + Im[b1] Re[b2] - Im[b]
```

> 0. 

> 0. 

> 0. 

> 0. 

The problem with this approach is catastrophic cancellation in the imaginary parts:

```
Re[a1] Im[a2]
Im[a1] Re[a2]
```

> 3.1848044765212715

> -3.1848044765212733

```
Re[b1] Im[b2]
Im[b1] Re[b2]
```

> 3.184804476521272

> -3.184804476521273

As you can see the two summands are of almost equal magnitudes, but with opposite signs.

So it seems that this can be blamed solely on *Mathematica*'s product routine for complex function. But I am pretty sure, this would also happen in C or C++ with the `-Ofast` or `-ffast-math` flags...

Comment: "I work under macos on Apple Silicon. I get these results:" Do you use ARM native compilation? Same as in Windows 11 up to last digit in hidden floats. That means the bug comes from the difference "-0.8090169943749475/0.587785252292473 changes to -0.8090169943749473/0.5877852522924732 with no reason whatsover" You need to use Trace to understand where the error comes from and to see this error. Trace is very small in this case.

Comment: I do use ARM compilation, yes. The problems lies solely in the product; the factors are computed accurately. I come more and more to the conclusion that _compontent-wise_ precision in complex multiplication cannot be guaranteed; only _norm-wise_ precision. The actual exact imaginary part of your number is `0`. So computing the relative error would always entail some division by `0` (or by a very small number).

Comment: That is not the main problem I am conserned with here. That error is small and improved with FullSimplify; we all know how slow FullSimplify is, so it cannot just be auto used. It makes the order of operations very different. Again, operations inside Trace have variable precision, because there is autotracking of it... What you showed here is not interesting, because all interesting things happen in C code, not even inside Trace. Lower level, x86_64 assembly. I can reproduce my problem with Linux vs windows even without Trace though. See:  https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2851685

Comment: I didn't see much of a question in the original post. As for the basic example, some of the difference can be seen comparing `In[282]:= InputForm[N[1/(-1)^(6/5)]]
Out[282]//InputForm=
-0.8090169943749473 + 0.5877852522924732*I`, which is computed under the hood as `In[281]:= InputForm[N@1/Exp[I*Pi*6/5]]
Out[281]//InputForm=
-0.8090169943749473 + 0.5877852522924732*I`, with `In[283]:= InputForm[1/(-1)^N[(6/5)]]
Out[283]//InputForm=
-0.8090169943749475 + 0.587785252292473*I`. Once the approximate value is in that power, chances for to-the-last-ULP computation drop considerably.

Comment: "Why do you think that happens?" That is the question. Again you are all jumping on the change after FullSimplify, while the question is about Linux (Wolfram Cloud) bug vs windows 11, both after FullSimplify. And again, that difference is not important because the bug happens on one of the operations only, as you can see in Trace.

Comment: "Again, operations inside Trace have variable precision, because there is autotracking of it..." I don't get what you mean by that. When you apply `N`, then everything should be converted to doubles (64bit floating point). And IIRC variable precision tracking should be deactivated quite early in the process for performance reasons. So we are in the floating point realm.

Comment: Did you check what trace prints? It does not have 0.5877852522924731. It loses one digit, and prints  0.587785252292473. please check the trace! Why cannot you? See 1/(-1.)^1.2 part, yet 1/(-1.)^1.2 just typed in has 1 in the end. So that is why I think it has some autotracking, as it sees you do not need all precision. Trace[-(-1)^(1/5) Beta[-1, -(6/5), 11/5] // N, TraceInternal -> True, 
 TraceDepth -> 10]

Comment: How am I supposed to run and see the trace on _your_ system?

Comment: No, `1/(-1.)^1.2` won't have autotracking. Whenever one operand is floating point, _Mathematica_ converts the other operands also to floating point representation. That is, _Mathematica_ first computes `(-1.)^1.2` and gets ``-0.8090169943749475` -0.587785252292473` I`` as result. Then it computes the inverse of this number, which it computes to be ``-0.8090169943749476` + 0.5877852522924731` I``. Which seems to be correct, too (up to floating point errors).

Comment: Okay, on Wolfram Cloud it gets ``-0.8090169943749476 - 0.587785252292473` I`` for ``(-1.`)^1.2``. So what? This involves an `exp` or a `pow` function. You push floating point numbers in -- and you have to expect to get floating point numbers out. With the rounding errors from the C math library used underneath. Which is system dependend. (Observe that all but the last digit are correct.)

Comment: "That result is wrong then, it has one less digit in complex part than in real and it is not the same as in normal execution." Yes, we have a floating point error in the very last place: 1 is replaced by 0. But this is _allowed_, no?

Comment: "Which is system dependend." Oh, so you use glibc on linux and AMD libm on windows? Okay that is the anwer. Thanks. "But this is allowed, no? " What is? lowering precision? I do not know, you say there is no autotracking here.

Comment: It does not _lower_ the precision. It just does not show you the last digit. Because it is 0. And yes, that is what I am saying: The floating point math libraries are system dependend, i.e., they depend on (i) architecture, (ii) OS, and even (iii) the compiler used. It can even depend on further external libraries that are linked. For example, _Mathematica_ uses Intel MKL quite a lot, e.g. for vectorized floating point calculation.  But MKL does not run natively on ARM. So one is _forced_ to link to another library. The best to expect is low relative error.

Comment: "It does not lower the precision. It just does not show you the last digit. Because it is 0." But it is not 0. 1/(-1.)^1.2 will give you 1 there in normal execution and it is still 0 in Trace. Moreover, -0.8090169943749476 or ..75 are both wrong, it must be -0.8090169943749474.

Comment: Yes, and no. You are right: `a = SetPrecision[N[Power[(-1), 6/5], 100], $MachinePrecision]` would show you ``-0.8090169943749474... - 0.5877852522924731... I``. But ``b = -0.8090169943749476 - 0.587785252292473` I`` is not wrong either because the relative error `Abs[a-b]/Abs[a]` is ``1.5700924586837752`*^-16``. This is not less than `0.5 $MachineEpsilon`, but closeby. It's definitely less than `$MachineEpsilon` and thus people would agree, it's (almost) as good as you can get with double precision.

Comment: And `0.5 $MachineEpsilon` is required by IEEE 754 only for elementary arithmetic operations like `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, and `sqrt`. Not for `exp` or `pow`.

Comment: "required by IEEE 754 only for elementary arithmetic" exp and pow are implemented in software. Even sincos is nowadays done in software because of a bug in Intel CPUs in fsin instruction. https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2014/10/09/intel-underestimates-error-bounds-by-1-3-quintillion/

Comment: BTW, 1.5700924586837752*^-16 is 1.570092458683775`*^-16 on windows 11. So some differences with ARM too. Trace from Windows 11: https://pastebin.com/HF4ARp1Z

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the answer is that on Windows it is possible to use Intel C/C++ math.h libm library, which is much better than glibc on windows, indeed accuracy.pdf paper above shows that pow is just 0.817 for glibc (and gcc has its own pow, will not use glibc one) compared to 0.515 ulp for Intel C++ compiler library version 2023.0. And again, here we have complex numbers, that paper does not actually check those. That is worse than core-math, which is ideal 0.5 ulp.

I would love to clarify this and have https://gitlab.inria.fr/core-math/core-math/-/blob/master/src/binary32/pow/powf.c to be used on Mathematica on Linux.